# JMdns ServiceListner doesn't find all services,

Tags: java, jmdns

Hi I created sample jmdns serviceListner, When i run it , It should continue to list services as it finds, But with this my program, It list few services when run and after that it does not list any service. And i have dns-sd in my google chrome browser, So when i browse services in chrome, at that time my program list other services, Otherwise my program doesn't list services. I don't get why ServiceListner itself doesn't detect any subsequent events.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String type = "_my-app._tcp.local.";
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> ifc = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (ifc.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface anInterface = ifc.nextElement();
        if (anInterface.isUp()) {
            Enumeration<InetAddress> addr = anInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (addr.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress address = addr.nextElement();
                final JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create(address, type);
                ServiceListenerClass aClass = new ServiceListenerClass();
                jmdns.addServiceListener(type, aClass);              

            }
        }
    }


}

public static class ServiceListenerClass implements ServiceListener {
    public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
        event.getDNS().requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName(), true);
    }

    public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent event) {
        System.out.println((count--) + " " + event.getInfo().getName());
    }

    public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) {
            System.out.println((count++) + " :Res: " + event.getInfo().getName() + " " + event.getInfo().getPort() + " " + event.getInfo().getApplication()
                    + " " + event.getInfo().getDomain() + " " + event.getInfo().getKey());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why  do you bind to each individual interface?

Comment: Since am running it on pc So to make sure it can recieve form all interfaces, Also tried without binding to the interfaces But result was same, So i dont get what is the problem, And amazingly when i browse dns-sd from chrome while running above code start listing remaining services.

Comment: The 0.0.0.0 interface should listen to all interfaces.

Comment: if i do with simple "final JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create();", Even then it doesn't work. So think ServiceListner is not receiving all events.

Comment: By specifying `type = _my-app._tcp.local.` will resulting JmDNS discover only the service of type my-app. Try using `type = _tcp.local.`, this should gives your more results.

Comment: Thank Yorkw..But need only this specific type of service, So we gave **type= _my-app._tcp.local.**

Comment: I dont know why 3.4.1 does not discover all the services. But latest snapshot(3.4.2-SNAPSHOT) from Revision 336 of svn does work fine. Solved

Comment: @twid where did you find that (3.4.2-SNAPSHOT) version? Ive got the same problem here.. =\

Comment: Ok, found it here https://github.com/jmdns/jmdns/releases but it still doesn't work =\ i've got 2 devices but they only find themselves...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem two.
The problem might come from your firewall settings.

In my case the javaw.exe had access to all incoming calls but could not send anything to anyone as the firewall blocked it.

Try turning of the firewall to test you programm and to be shure thats not the firewall causing the problem.

Comment: Thank I did tried that but didn't worked and  as i mentioned in my last comment i did updated to new snapshot and then worked fine.. what i noticed was JMDNS was receiving multicat messages from server but wasn't able to deliver to service Listener class..

Comment: Why are you postincrement you count variable and not preincrement?? (change it to --count and ++count to have the correct amount of detected services)

Comment: Yes You are right... But my problem was JmDNS Library wasn't able to deliver all service events to Listener class(ServiceListenerClass). So Unless and until ServiceListenerClass could not get any event notification it can not display service information.  Thx...

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Starting java with the following argument solved it for me:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```